# Pagination in PHP with N number of elements per page

Tags: php

I need a little bit of help.

I have an XML file as a database. From it, I need to create a pagination with 25 elements per page with Next and Previous buttons, but with my skills I'm stuck at it.

At the moment, I've written this code, but every page it reset the ID from the database to 0, so it doesn't work.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("SITE_URL/database_gamecard.xml");

$ids = array();
$count = 0;

foreach($xml->gamecard as $id) {
    $ids[] = $id;
}

//Order IDs by url names
//usort ($ids, function($a, $b) {
    //$url = $id->url;
    //return strcmp($a[$url], $b[$url]);
//});

function PopulatePage($id) {
    $url = $id->url;
    $img = $id->img;
    
    echo '<a class="darken" href="' . $url . '"><img width="320" height="240" src="' . $img . '"></a>';
}

function StopCount() {
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);
    $pageurl = "SITE_URL/list.php?page=";
    $count = 0;
    $page = $page + 1;
    $newurl = $pageurl . $page;

    echo "<a href='" . $newurl . "'>Next</a>";
}

//Test generating pages
foreach ($ids as $id) {
            
    $count++;
    
    if($page == 1) {
        PopulatePage($id);
            
        if($count == 25) {
            StopCount();
            break;
        }
    }
    if($page == 2) {
        PopulatePage($id);

        if($count == 25) {
            StopCount();
            break;      
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Hint (one of the ways): you can determine the records to display based on the Page number and the number of records displayed per page (say 25). So for page=1, it should display the 1st 25 records, for page=2, it should skip 25 records and then display the next 25 records, for page=2, it should skip (25*2) records and then display the next 25 records

Comment: I was trying something similar, but I can't add or skip IDs since $id is not an integer but an array from the XML file.

Comment: Echoing $ids doesn't do anything at all, I can print_r it to show what nodes it contains (such as its ID and sub-nodes as genre, release date, etc...)

Comment: Ok so, thanks to your initial idea I've managed to make it work, thanks!